# MDDR in user agent string

Tags: user-agent

What do MDDR means in a user agent string?

`Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; MDDR; InfoPath.1; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; OfficeLiveConnector.1.4; OfficeLivePatch.1.3)`

Comment: Where was this agent string found? What is the context of this post?

Comment: of course we get some answers just after my bounty expired. *sigh* i wish i could give you guys the 50 rep that expired :(

Answer (score 2):

Most puzzling, this question has been asked since a while ;)

My hunch based on http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/msie-history.html and http://www.vistaheads.com/forums/microsoft-public-internetexplorer-general/460619-what-do-mddr-stands-user-agent-string.html and http://dell.msn.com/?pc=MDDC is that MDDR is a variant of MDDC and basically it would be an OEM modified version (by Dell) of IE.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure, but some links that might be of help:

http://sillydog.org/forum/sdt_15762.php : User forum that displays user agent strings.  There's a member of the Bing outreach team (bingnate) who has that in his user agent strings.  You might be able to ask him.

http://user-agent-string.info User agent analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this user-agent almost 10 years after this question is asked and this is what I found.

The description of the `MDDR / MDDRJS` fragment is **Dell**.

Source: https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/learn/unknown-user-agent-fragments/

Answer (score -1):

Wikipedia has this listed this abbreviation as Mobile DDR - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDDR

Comment: So you really think that the type of DRAM would be part of the user agent string ? I don't think so.